# CustomView with touch handling inside RecyclerView with ItemTouchHelper

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, touch-event

I have a RecyclerView with an ItemTouchHelper using a SimpleCallback attached to it. This allows horizontal swiping as well as long-click-drag to swap items.

```
    RecyclerView rv = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    rv.setAdapter(new TestAdapter(this)); // adds 4 entries with CustomViews
    new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.UP|ItemTouchHelper.DOWN, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT|ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {

        @Override
        public boolean isItemViewSwipeEnabled() {
            Log.i("touchtest", "swipe enabled request");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLongPressDragEnabled() {
            Log.i("touchtest", "drag enabled request");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

        }
    }).attachToRecyclerView(rv);
```

Some of my ViewHolders inside the RecyclerView have a custom View as its root, that needs to detect horizontal dragging.

I setup my CustomView to intercept all events, requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent as long as touch events are detected, then log and consume all of them.

```
public class CustomView extends FrameLayout {

  public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
  }

  public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
  }


  @Override
  public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    logEvent(ev, "intercept");
    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    logEvent(event, "touch");
    return true;
  }

  private void logEvent(MotionEvent ev, String callback) {
    String eventName;
    switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            eventName = "down";
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            eventName = "up";
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            eventName = "move";
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            eventName = "cancel";
            break;
        default:
            eventName = "untracked";
            break;
      }
      Log.i("touchtest", callback + " " + eventName);
  }
}
```

**Problem:** Even with the absolute consumption of every event, the ItemTouchHelper still detects the long-click-drag. With the first down-event, CustomView does intercept and consume the events correctly. Once i take my finger of the screen and put it back on, the second down-event isn't even received by my onInterceptTouchEvent. Instead the ItemTouchHelper continues directly with the long-click-drag and moves the items.

```
I/touchtest: intercept down
I/touchtest: touch down
I/touchtest: drag enabled request
I/touchtest: touch move
I/touchtest: touch move
I/touchtest: touch move
I/touchtest: touch up
```

**Question:** How does my View have to behave, to receive and consume the events correctly? I tested this with a RecyclerView inside the RecyclerView and there was no such strange behaviour. Are there any other calls or something to let the RecyclerView know that it should cancel ongoing touch handlings?

Comment: Why use ItemTouchHelper with views that need to handle their own touch detection? Seems like conflicting behavior. Also, the touch helper is not "detecting" long-click - it's checking if it's enabled or not: `isLongPressDragEnabled`.

Comment: @dominicoder As described, on the second down-event the TouchHelper consumes it and performs the item-swap-drag behaviour. The log doesn't show exactly that, yes.

I have different item types with different views in my Adapter. This is just a simplistic example to show the issue. My actual RecyclerView will only contain 1 Item which requires its own drag logic. Generally the long-click-drag behaviour is desired, unless the item detects its own gestures.

Comment: OK. I think you're supposed to return false for `isLongPressDragEnabled` and `isItemViewSwipeEnabled` in that case, then.

Comment: @dominicoder But the View is supposed to have the same long-drag and swipe function as the others in the RecyclerView. Only if it detects its specific gesture (drag in the right half) it shouldn't have the ItemTouchHelper behaviour. And as you can see from the logs, isLongPressDragEnabled is called before move-events are dispatched. So i can't disable it in time that way.
Looking at the Source of RecyclerView and ItemTouchHelper it seems like it is not handling requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent correctly. It will still intercept, even when it was requested not to.